# Trouble with very basic template function

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

Outside of work, I'm going through my college textbooks and trying to work through old work in an attempt to keep sharp.  I'm running into this issue in my old data structures book, though:

```
template <typename Comparable> 
const Comparable & findMax(const vector<Comparable> & a) {
    int maxIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < a.size(); i++) {
        if (a[i] > a[maxIndex]) {
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }

    return a[maxIndex];
}
```

Give me the errors:

- missing type specifier - int assumed
- unrecognizable template declaration/definition
- syntax error missing ',' before '<'

I'm incredibly rusty (VB.Net has rendered me kinda weak).

What am I doing wrong here? I've looked around several topics, played with the definition, etc, and I still don't have a clue.

Comment: It works well [here](http://rextester.com/WHP31251) with `Comparable` is `int`.

Comment: Here's the kicker: I don't even have a call to it. It doesn't even compile.  The above is the exact code for it. This is all in Visual Studio, so maybe I'm missing something that has nothing to do with the code itself.

Comment: I guess you forget to `#include <vector>`. http://rextester.com/XBGBQX89240

Comment: I had the code initially in a header file, which threw the error.  I then threw the code into a standard source file. Same issues. If I threw the function into my source file with my main function, bam, it worked.  In order to keep things separate, I threw the code back into the .cpp file, added the same reference to the master header (which was referenced earlier and contained the vector include) and slapped on a "using namespace std;".  It magically worked. I then put an #include statement in the file with the main function I can reference everything. Can you tell me why this worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forget to `#include <vector>`. Otherwise it should work [well](http://rextester.com/WHP31251).

BTW: You might check whether the vector is empty before `return a[maxIndex];`. Otherwise an invalid reference might be returned, which will lead to [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: I had the include statement and it still wouldn't work. Come to find out it was a build order issue; the master head for the project was referencing the header file that declared the findMax function prior to referencing the vector import. One switch and everything was beautiful. Thanks for the help!